# AndroidManifest.xml encoding is not readable after gradle assemble task

Tags: android, gradle

I wanted to explore the generated AndroidManifest.xml of my .apk and I realised that the format was not readable.

Both debug and release apks contain the encoded manifest file. How is that possible when progaurd is disabled?

Does Gradle modify the encoding during assemble process?

Is there anyway to disable that feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How is that possible when progaurd is disabled?

ProGuard has nothing to do with it. XML (manifest and resources) is converted into a "binary XML" format as part of the build process.

> Does Gradle modify the encoding during assemble process?

Not specifically. Creating this binary XML is part of the build tools in general, whether invoked from Gradle, Ant, Eclipse, or whatever.

> Is there anyway to disable that feature?

No. There are tools available that can decompile an APK, and some of those will convert the binary XML back into a text representation. Or use **`aapt dump badging`**. Or, use an on-device inspector, like [App Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.japanesecrackers.appbrowser).

Comment: Absolutely right. Thanks very much... In the past I was using apktool to extract the files of an apk and I had the impression that the AndroidManifest was not encoded.

Answer (score 0):

The App Browser on-device inspector mentioned by Mark doesn't display the Android manifest very well (since it doesn't resolve resource references).  There's a much better view given by [App Detective](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zmarties.detective)